# Can I pass a table as a parameter when executing a storedproc?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

Is it possible to pass a table (or table variable) as a parameter of a storedproc when executing the storedproc. If yes then how.  I need an example.

Please help.

Comment: While this isn't possible with SQL Server 2005, it is possible with SQL Server 2008

Comment: If you mean for SQL Server 2008, there is a sample here:
http://www.builderau.com.au/program/sqlserver/soa/Passing-table-valued-parameters-in-SQL-Server-2008/0,339028455,339282577,00.htm

Answer (score 1):

In sql server 2005, No.

You can use xmldocs, or comma delimited string (using a split function)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString]
(
        @String VARCHAR(8000) ,
        @Delimiter  VARCHAR(10)
)
RETURNS @RetTable TABLE(
        String varchar(1000)
)
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @i INT ,
            @j INT
    SELECT  @i = 1
    WHILE @i <= LEN(@String)
    BEGIN
        SELECT  @j = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @String, @i)
        IF @j = 0
        BEGIN
            SELECT  @j = LEN(@String) + 1
        END
        INSERT  @RetTable SELECT SUBSTRING(@String, @i, @j - @i)
        SELECT  @i = @j + LEN(@Delimiter)
    END
    RETURN
END
```

see also

[passing-lists-to-sql-server-2005-with-xml-parameters](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2007/02/16/passing-lists-to-sql-server-2005-with-xml-parameters.aspx)

and

[beginning-sql-server-2005-xml-programming](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/beginning-sql-server-2005-xml-programming/)

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle you can use TYPES and OBJECTS to achieve this IIRC. Could you not use a CURSOR/LOOP though? If the reason you're doing this is to capture dynamic data?

```
   CURSOR c_my_cursor IS
      SELECT * 
      FROM my_table;

BEGIN

   FOR x IN c_my_c LOOP
       IF x.employeeID IS NULL THEN
          .....
       END IF;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: I don't think you can use this method if the table name is to be a variable. You'd have to revert to REF CURSORS that can be bound to a dynamic statement, but you loose a lot of type safety then.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not on SQL Server 2008 (where you can use [table-valued parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx)), then you can get some other ideas for sharing data between stored procedures from Erland's great article:

http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html

Erland talks about table-valued parameters as well, and goes into great depth explaining why the current implementation (read only) is not quite good enough:

http://www.sommarskog.se/tableparam.html